# Need to convert the following css to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have my css like this

```
#myid.myclass{
    top: 50px !important;
    right: 50px !important;
  }
```

How to write this in jquery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$("#myid.myclass").css({
   "top": "50px !important",
   "right": "50px !important"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    $("#myid").css('top','50px').css('right','50px');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myid').css({'top': '50px !important', 'right': '50px !important'});
```